# Error executing simple SQL Server stored procedure "failed when converting the varchar value"

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this stored procedure in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE display_user_name
    @userID INT,
    @user_name VARCHAR(250) OUTPUT    
AS   
    SET NOCOUNT ON;  

    SELECT @user_name = first_name +' '+ last_name
    FROM User_Table
    WHERE userID = @userID;

    RETURN @user_name
GO
```

and I get this error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'john1 doe1' to data type int.

When I run the stored procedure, I see that it creates a variable `@return_value` and it declares it as `INT`, this is the code that is generated when I right click and run the stored procedure

```
DECLARE @return_value INT,
        @user_name VARCHAR(250)

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[display_user_name]
            @userID = 1,
            @user_name = @user_name OUTPUT

SELECT  @user_name as N'@user_name'

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

How will I need to modify my original stored procedure so I don't get this error?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Stored procedures return an int. There is no changing that. You either need to use an output parameter or select the value in your procedure so it will be in a result set. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is the documentation about RETURN.

Comment: Actually just looked at this again. Simply remove the return statement in your procedure. You already have it as an output parameter.

Comment: Thanks, I get the user_name as a result, and I get a 0 as a Return value, so I would imagine the front end app would have to read that result right?

Comment: Remove `RETURN @user_name`.

Comment: In the front end you would get the result set from your procedure. Read the documentation about RETURN (I posted it above).